# How to use Excel to calculate bitwise XOR in hexadecimal format?

Tags: excel, hex, xor, bitwise-xor, vba

I have two cells with a string of bits:

`1747F6001E00DB2XXXXX28FE5257645C`
and
`1C6262C8DBF510F655XXXXXA3BDA58AC`

I want to XOR the two together so that the result would be something like  `0B2594C8C5F5CXXXXX190014698D3CF0`.

I know that I need to use a bitwise XOR operation in Excel, as bitwise XOR calculators work online, but they give me the option to choose between hexadecimal and binary input data. BITXOR should work, but it does not work for hexadecimal inputs.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With a formula, Text to Columns Fixed width each character separate (say A1:AF1 and A2:AF2):

```
=DEC2HEX(BITXOR(HEX2DEC(A1),HEX2DEC(A2)))
```

copied across to suit. Stitch back together with [CONCATENATE](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/CONCATENATE-function-8f8ae884-2ca8-4f7a-b093-75d702bea31d) if required as a string in a single cell (or copy into Word and Replace all the tabs, `^t`, with nothing).

Unfortunately BITXOR was not introduced until Excel 2011 / Excel 2013.

[image: SO33031399 example]

Comment: Thanks for your efforts. Hmm, I like this approach, but I'm trying now to figure out how I could do this approach for 100,000 first inputs(Line 1 in your example) and 1 unique second input (Line 2).

Comment: I really prefer pur excel formula solution to scripts.

Comment: `BINHEX(BITXOR(HEXBIN(A1) ; HEXBIN(A2)))`  should work better

Answer (score 1):

An approach for two hex-strings in equal length.

```
Sub approach()

 s1 = "1747F6001E00DB266F5728FE5257645C"
 s2 = "1C6262C8DBF510F6554E28EA3BDA58AC"

 If Len(s1) <> Len(s2) Then Exit Sub

 sRes = ""
 For i = 1 To Len(s1)
  vRes = Val("&H" & Mid(s1, i, 1)) Xor Val("&H" & Mid(s2, i, 1))
  sRes = sRes & Hex(vRes)
 Next

 Debug.Print sRes

End Sub
```

XOR each digit of the two hex-values as there is no need for an carry since it is not an addition.

Btw. `BITXOR` will only work up to 2^48-1. You have a value range up to 16^32-1.

Comment: To be completely honest, I am not even sure how to run your code.

I'll admit, I am not an expert, so I am sorry if you feel like I am wasting your time.

I have put it into a module, but I have no idea how to actually run the macro, when I click "run macro", nothing happens.

Comment: Have a look at the immediate window in the VBA editor. See https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/kb/165517 - scroll down till USING THE IMMEDIATE WINDOW.